# How to make a customize user input in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

The tracking number input has a fixed format: ab-cdefg-h. The first character (a) must be a digit in between 1 and 9 (inclusive). The second character (b) is an English character in uppercase. Next is a hyphen (-). The fourth character (c) is an English character in uppercase. It is then followed by four even-numbered digits (i.e., d, e, f, g can be 0, 2, 4, 6 and 8 only). Next is a hyphen. The last character (h) is a number representing the month, hence “h” can be 1 to 12. If the format is not correct, the text “This field is not valid” will be shown next to the text box as in Figure partb_3.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks like requirement list, what is your question?

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I would look into field masking

Comment: You can call a function on change event on the input field in which you can the pass the string entered by user and then in the function you match letters according to your requirements and set a Boolean variable to whether show or not the red text. You can also try regex.

Comment: By only providing a screenshot which tells you that something is wrong when parsing the tracking ID might not be sufficient to answer your question. Provide some code and try to reformulate your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
document.getElementById('f').onsubmit = function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    let pattern=/^\d{1}[A-Z]{1}-[A-Z]{1}(0|2|4|6|8){4}-([0-9]|10|11|12){1}$/;
    let id = document.querySelector('#id').value;
    console.log(id,pattern);
    if(!pattern.test(id)){
        document.querySelector('#err').style.display = "inline-block";
        document.querySelector('#res').innerHTML = '';
    }else{
        document.querySelector('#res').innerHTML = id + " , we will inform you as soon as possible!";
        document.querySelector('#err').style.display = "none";
    }
    this.reset();
}
```

```html
 <form id='f'>
        <input type="text" id="id"/>
        <div id='err' style="color: red;display: none;">This field is not valid</div>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="checking">
        <div id='res'></div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example with a regex (almost self explanatory) which you could use to check

```js
const regex = /\d{1}[A-Z]{1}-[A-Z]{1}[0,2,4,6,8]{4}-[1-9]{1}[0,2]{0,1}$/;
const strings = [
  '1A-B1234-19',
  '1A-B0204-12',
  '1A-B0204-c',
  '11-B0204-12',
  '1A-B2228-0',
  '1A-B2228-1',
];

strings.forEach( string => {
  console.log('Test: ' + string + ': ' + regex.test(string));
});
```

now with the above regex you can check every change on the input like so

```js
const regex = /\d{1}[A-Z]{1}-[A-Z]{1}[0,2,4,6,8]{4}-[1-9]{1}[0,2]{0,1}$/;

var element = document.querySelector('.the-input');
element.addEventListener('input', event => {
   let string = event.target.value;
   console.log('Test: ' + string + ': ' + regex.test(string));
});
```

```html
<input class="the-input" type="text" value="1A-B0204-12" >
```

Follow this link to find out more about the above regex: https://regex101.com/r/gOMbGh/2
let me know in the comments if something is unclear, I will then update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using a JQuery plugin like [jQuery Mask Plugin](https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/docs.html).

In your code you can do something like this:

```
const maskFormat = "1A-B1234-12";
$(selector).mask(maskFormat);
```

For the validation you can use a regular expression as @caramba said to check each part in the input field.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need JavaScript here.

Using a `pattern` attribute with the `required` attribute and a CSS `:invalid` selector can make it work (it also prevents submitting invalid input):

```css
input + .invalidfield{
  visibility: hidden;
  color: red;
}
input:invalid + .invalidfield{
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div>
    <input type="text" pattern="\d[A-Z]-[A-Z][0,2,4,6,8]{4}-(?:[1-9]|1[0-2])" required />
    <span class="invalidfield">This field isn't valid!</span>
  </div>
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```